# Ignoring count reset at specified point in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a `dataframe` like this (**edited**; adding a grouping variable `measurement_type`):

```
data <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c(rep(1, 10),
                                    rep(2, 10))),
                   measurement_type = as.factor(c(rep("type_1", 5),
                                                  rep("type_2", 5),
                                                  rep("type_1", 5),
                                                  rep("type_2", 5))),
                   measurement_time = as.POSIXct(c("2014-06-17 04:00:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 11:52:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 18:58:00",
                                                   "2014-06-18 02:05:00",
                                                   "2014-06-18 08:00:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 05:27:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 11:10:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 17:02:00",
                                                   "2014-06-17 23:56:00",
                                                   "2014-06-18 07:01:00",
                                                   "2014-07-03 16:01:00",
                                                   "2014-07-03 19:19:00",
                                                   "2014-07-03 23:55:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 08:08:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 13:55:00",
                                                   "2014-07-03 22:12:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 08:59:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 14:10:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 17:00:00",
                                                   "2014-07-04 23:00:00")),
                   amount = c(350,470,310,470,650,
                              175,275,45,255,395,
                              130,460,540,790,69,
                              80,210,58,147,326),
                   entry_time = as.POSIXct(c(rep("2014-06-17 01:53:00", 10),
                                             rep("2014-07-03 14:35:00", 10))))
```

The Subjects with `ID 1` and `ID 2` enter at a specified `entry_time` and thereafter, cumulative `amounts` are measured at specific `measurement_times`. However, each day at noon, the amount is set back to zero again and counting starts again (from zero). What I would like to achieve is that once a break at noon happens (and therefore a reset to zero), it keeps adding the new newly starting cumulative amount to that already accumulated before noon (grouped by the grouping variable `measurement_type`).

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Istrel I almost got the right output using the provided answer:

```
data %>% as_tibble() %>%
  # Check 12 hours passed --> `pm` column
  mutate(pm = format(measurement_time, "%H") >= 12) %>%
  mutate(date_fct = format(measurement_time, "%Y_%d")) %>%
  # Group by ID and `pm`
  group_by(ID, measurement_type, date_fct, pm) %>%
  # Turn cumsum into actual values
  mutate(amount_act = amount - lag(amount, default = 0)) %>%
  # Cumsum over ID
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID, measurement_type) %>%
  mutate(amount_cums = cumsum(amount_act)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(pm, date_fct, amount_act))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 20 x 6
   ID    measurement_type measurement_time    amount entry_time          amount_cums
   <fct> <fct>            <dttm>               <dbl> <dttm>                    <dbl>
 1 1     type_1           2014-06-17 04:00:00    350 2014-06-17 01:53:00         350
 2 1     type_1           2014-06-17 11:52:00    470 2014-06-17 01:53:00         470
 3 1     type_1           2014-06-17 18:58:00    310 2014-06-17 01:53:00         780
 4 1     type_1           2014-06-18 02:05:00    470 2014-06-17 01:53:00        1250
 5 1     type_1           2014-06-18 08:00:00    650 2014-06-17 01:53:00        1430
 6 1     type_2           2014-06-17 05:27:00    175 2014-06-17 01:53:00         175
 7 1     type_2           2014-06-17 11:10:00    275 2014-06-17 01:53:00         275
 8 1     type_2           2014-06-17 17:02:00     45 2014-06-17 01:53:00         320
 9 1     type_2           2014-06-17 23:56:00    255 2014-06-17 01:53:00         530
10 1     type_2           2014-06-18 07:01:00    395 2014-06-17 01:53:00         925
11 2     type_1           2014-07-03 16:01:00    130 2014-07-03 14:35:00         130
12 2     type_1           2014-07-03 19:19:00    460 2014-07-03 14:35:00         460
13 2     type_1           2014-07-03 23:55:00    540 2014-07-03 14:35:00         540
14 2     type_1           2014-07-04 08:08:00    790 2014-07-03 14:35:00        1330
15 2     type_1           2014-07-04 13:55:00     69 2014-07-03 14:35:00        1399
16 2     type_2           2014-07-03 22:12:00     80 2014-07-03 14:35:00          80
17 2     type_2           2014-07-04 08:59:00    210 2014-07-03 14:35:00         290
18 2     type_2           2014-07-04 14:10:00     58 2014-07-03 14:35:00         348
19 2     type_2           2014-07-04 17:00:00    147 2014-07-03 14:35:00         437
20 2     type_2           2014-07-04 23:00:00    326 2014-07-03 14:35:00         616
```

As you can see, the cumulative sums for noon breaks get updated correctly. However, in case of overnight cases, the code adds the amount of after midnight to the total count of before midnight. However, at midnight there is no count reset, and the amount simply should be keeping cumulating to the before midnight amount (no count reset).
However, in the output shown above, the cumulative amount is added to the before midnight value: for example line 10, where it adds the value of 395 to the amount_cums of 530 (line 9), whereas it should simply be adding the difference to the last value (395 - 255 = 140), the correct amount_cums being 670 for line 10.

Any idea how I could adapt your code?

Comment: So the problem was not in my code, but in the fact that you provided incomplete data (there was no `measurement_type` variable in the initial example). If this is the case, I suggest you enter this variable into the original example, I will update my code and you can accept it as correct.

Comment: Edited, adding a grouping variable.

Comment: @Istrel. See the update.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest this strategy. First, group the data by ID, date (year_month_day) and AM/PM time tag. Then convert the cumulative sum to the original values in each group. Then recalculate the cumulative sum in groups by ID and date.

The solution could look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_alt <- data %>% as_tibble() %>%
    # Check 12 hours passed --> `pm` column
    mutate(pm = format(measurement_time, "%H") >= 12) %>%
    mutate(date_fct = format(measurement_time, "%Y_%d")) %>%
    # Group by ID and `pm`
    group_by(ID, measurement_type, date_fct, pm) %>%
    # Turn cumsum into actual values
    mutate(amount_act = amount - lag(amount, default = 0)) %>%
    # Cumsum over ID
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(ID, measurement_type) %>%
    mutate(amount_cums = cumsum(amount_act)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-c(pm, date_fct, amount_act))
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my sample dataframe, thanks a lot!. However, when I have samples that pass midnight too (as I have in my original dataframe), it starts to add to the morning amount of the last day. Any idea how to overcome this (I can update the question, if you prefer)

Comment: Yes, could you add an example with an over midnight case?

Comment: See the update. Any idea how I might get the right output?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want cumulative values for the entire observation period. Then you need to remove the condition of the date from the last `group_by`. Check the new update.

Comment: I finally found time to look at the project again. It works perfectly for the over-noon-cases, however, for over-midnight-cases, there is still an unsolved issue, see the update in the question above. Any idea how I might adapt your code to get the desired output?
Thank you so much for your help!